format of RISCV instruction encoding in Spike?
In QEMU RISCV instruction sub encoded according to RISCV spec,
where dots represent variable bits, which encode 2 source and 1 destination register indices.
sub      0100000 .....    ..... 000 ..... 0110011 

However, in Spike there are following definitions:
#define MATCH_C_SUB 0x8c01 //'0b1000110000000001'
#define MASK_C_SUB 0xfc63 //'0b1111110001100011'

How could I take QEMU-like representation and convert it to Spike's (for example to add a new instruction)?
Thanks
I do not understand how instruction encoding represented in Spike

Replace all the dots with 0s to get the MATCH value.  Replace all the dots with 0s, and everything else with 1s, to get the MASK value.  The test is performed via (value & MASK) == MATCH.  Note that your QEMU and Spike examples are different instructions, which is probably why you were having a hard time figuring it out - the Spike instruction is the compressed version of SUB (16-bit) from the RV32C extension, rather than the standard SUB (32-bit).
